# kafka-pyspark: Kafka local installation becomes non-responsive while reading messages

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have a local **Apache Kafka** installation, and I am trying to read streaming messages (offsets set to earliest), but the pyspark code becomes non-responsive even when I am pushing messages from another shell. Following logs are the only ones I can see in the console:

```
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/12/12 02:08:31 WARN scheduler.FairSchedulableBuilder: Fair Scheduler configuration file not found so jobs will be scheduled in FIFO order. To use fair scheduling, configure pools in fairscheduler.xml or set spark.scheduler.allocation.file to a file that contains the configuration.
22/12/12 02:08:36 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
22/12/12 02:08:37 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
22/12/12 02:08:44 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
2022-12-12 02:08:44,981 - spark - INFO - Initiated Spark Session
2022-12-12 02:08:56,471 - stream - INFO - Writing to Console
22/12/12 02:08:56 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
22/12/12 02:08:56 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
22/12/12 02:08:56 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby. Visit https://s.apache.org/sbnn-error
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]
22/12/12 02:13:57 WARN internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-da2c6a76-b603-44ac-9db3-b8f4022a2044--500293921-driver-0] This member will leave the group because consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]
```

My server.properties is:

```
broker.id=1
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
log.dirs=/home/aiman/kafka_local/kafka_2.11-2.0.0/kafka-logs
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
max.poll.interval.ms=5
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
session.timeout.ms=3
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
```

My py-spark code is:

```
kafka_config = { 'checkpointLocation': '/user/aiman/checkpoint/kafka_local',
                 'kafka.bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092',
                 'subscribe': 'TEST_1',
                 'startingOffsets': '{"TEST_1":{"0":3}}'
               }
df = spark.readStream \
          .format("kafka") \
          .options(**kafka_config) \
          .load()
data = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)","offset","timestamp","partition")

data.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("truncate", False) \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

Is there anything specific that I need to set in server.properties?

Comment: The logs indicate Spark cannot connect, not a Kafka problem (unless Kafka isn't running). You could try Docker, for example - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb